# Is it possible to select multiple elements and perform the same action on all of them with Selenium IDE (latest version)?

Tags: selenium, selenium-ide

I'm new to Selenium and I'm trying to figure out with the latest version of the IDE for Firefox or Chrome how to select multiple elements (via css selector) and perform the same actions on each (e.g. clicking on the element, then choosing to generate a report for it).  I can't find any documentation on how to do this kind of thing for each element that matches the selection - I can only find how to do it once.  Any posts I've seen for doing something like this are very old and use javascript in a format unlike the way the current IDE works.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: The examples are behind a login.  So far what I've read with Selenium IDE is that if a selector matches more than one element, only the first one is used.  I'm wondering if it's possible with IDE (and perhaps a plugin if necessary) to use a selector that returns more than one element and to perform the same action (e.g. click) on each one in a loop.  I've done this in a Java app, but I'm not sure if it's possible in the IDE version.